# Difference between TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE and TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp-with-timezone

I ran the same statements in two different databases: my Local DB and [Oracle Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com).

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSDATE,
    timestamp_tmz TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
    timestamp_local_tmz TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE DEFAULT SYSDATE
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);

SELECT * FROM test;
```

*(all statements were executed at approximately the same time - 09:35 AM CET)*

**Results from my Local DB:**

```
TIMESTAMP: 10-JAN-23 09.35.32.000000000 AM
TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE: 10-JAN-23 09.35.32.000000000 AM EUROPE/BERLIN
TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE: 10-JAN-23 09.35.32.000000000 AM
```

**Results from Oracle Live:**

```
TIMESTAMP: 10-JAN-23 08.35.44.000000 AM 
TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE: 10-JAN-23 08.35.44.000000 AM US/PACIFIC   
TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE: 10-JAN-23 08.35.44.000000 AM
```

After seeing the results, my questions are:

- Why is Oracle Live's TIMESTAMP showing date in a different time zone (8.35 AM instead of 9.35 AM)?
- Why does Oracle Live's TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE return US/PACIFIC as time zone?
- Is there any difference between TIMESTAMP and TIME STAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The different data types are [described in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-3A1B7AC6-2EDB-4DDC-9C9D-223D4C72AC74).

> The TIMESTAMP data type is an extension of the DATE data type. It stores year, month, day, hour, minute, and second values. It also stores fractional seconds, which are not stored by the DATE data type.

> TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE is a variant of TIMESTAMP that includes a time zone region name or time zone offset in its value.

> TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE is another variant of TIMESTAMP. It differs from TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE as follows: data stored in the database is normalized to the database time zone, and the time zone offset is not stored as part of the column data. When users retrieve the data, Oracle Database returns it in the users' local session time zone.

You are seeing a difference because you have different timezones, and you are defaulting the values to `SYSDATE`, which is the system `DATE`.

In your local database the system time zone (`select dbtimezone from dual`) seems to be based on CET, while the Live SQL database seems to be based on UTC, as Oracle recommends. As CET is an hour ahead of UTC/GMT, that explains the one-hour difference.

The `TIMESTAMP` value is just a simple cast, i.e. `cast(SYSDATE as TIMESTAMP`), so you get the same value you would if you queried `SYSDATE` directly, with zero fractional seconds added.

For the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` it has to store a time zone, and it has to get that from somewhere, and by default it uses your *session* time zone, not the database time zone. In your local DB that also seems to be CET, but Live SQL is defaulting the *session* time zone to US Pacific time - not unreasonable, given where Oracle is based. So now it's effectively doing `from_tz(cast(SYSDATE as TIMESTAMP), SESSIONTIMEZONE)` for that value, where for you `SESSIONTIMEZONE` is CET in one database and US/Pacific in the other.

For the `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` it is doing the same, but then normalising that back to the database time zone for storage (effectively `cast(from_tz(cast(SYSDATE as TIMESTAMP), SESSIONTIMEZONE) at time zone DBTIMEZONE as TIMESTAMP)` - not actually that internally, but gives you the idea), and converting back from the database time zone to your session time zone again when it is queried.

In both databases, if you `alter session set time_zone = ...` before inserting, and again to a different value before querying, then you'll see different results - the displayed time portion will stay the same for the first two columns, but the time zone will change for the `WITH TIME ZONE`, and the time will change for the `WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/spmpkdUt) with different session time zones.

You can read more about all of this behaviour in the documentation I already linked to above.

---

If you use `SYSTIMESTAMP` instead of `SYSDATE` as the default for all of your columns then you will avoid the implicit conversion to your session time zone for the `WITH TIME ZONE` value, and that will always show the database time zone. The `LOCAL` column will still display in your session time zone, but they will all represent the same time. You will also still see the one-hour difference between the two databases, because they have different *database* time zones. You could consider defaulting the plain timestamp to `sys_extract_utc(SYSTIMESTAMP)`, or defaulting them all (or at least the first two) to `SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone 'UTC'`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fdlAmgdc) with UTC-normalised values.

Comment: I think *"For the TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE it is doing the same, but then normalising that back to UTC for storage"* is not fully correct. Should be *"For the TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE it is doing the same, but then normalising that back to `DBTIMEZONE` for storage"*

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - indeed, thank you for spotting that. Updated and expanded a bit.

Comment: Does TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE also take the date/time from SYSDATE like TIMESTAMP does? So it'd take: date/time from SYSDATE (then it's casted to TIMESTAMP) and then takes the time zone from SESSIONTIMEZONE, which may return a "wrong" date if the User and DB are in two different locations, isn't it? User in Tokyo adds a new TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE value (which is by default SYSDATE like the previous examples) on a Rome-based DB: it'll result in a Rome date/time but Tokyo time zone, correct?

Comment: @NicolòVitelli - yes, that's what you're seeing really. For all the values you have an hour discrepancy because the dbtimezones are UTC and CET; ignore that for a moment and assume both are UTC. For the TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE the time part stays the same while the *time zone* changes, based on your session settings; making them different points in time. If you use SYSTIMESTAMP instead of SYSDATE that will stop, and that will store the correct point in time.

Comment: @NicolòVitelli - another [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3h8vvmbW) showing (hopefully) that using SYSTIMESTAMP stops it being confused by the session time zone...